# adding link (url) to message when writing email with mu4e

Tags: email, mu4e

I recently started to use mu4e and maybe this is quite obvious, but how can I add an url with description to a message using mu4e?

Is there something like `[[url][description]]` as in org-mode?

Comment: do you want the url to be rendered as a link? I don't think that's possible, the mu4e editor only produces plain text emails (I think)

Comment: yes that was my idea...

Comment: actually, this might help: https://emacs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mu4e__email_client.html

Comment: To achieve this I normally blend mu4e and org-msg https://github.com/jeremy-compostella/org-msg